# Read old handwritten Text

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

A few months ago I bought an old book, it was printed in ~1801 and it has a name entry (?) at the first page.

[image: http://saved.im/mtg3njc0c2i2/dscn4301.jpg]

Anybody can fully read that? I personally cannot. What I think:

> ... ... Auktion im Jahr 1813. ... ... Expedition ... Lit. Zeitung  ...

Anyone see more than that?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, thanks to the person editing my post (with the image for example), I didnt know where to put it and I also didnt knew any other tags to give. Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, pictures of what the letters look like in Kurrentschrift are here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift .

Comment: Note, that the middle line contains some non-kurrent letters as e, i, u, n and g.

Answer (score 10):

as far as i can read it:

> Aus der Auktion im Jahr 1813
>   von der Expedition der Lit. Zeitung
>   gehalten

if it's verb it's strange because it should end with n or t and I see none of it.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of makes sense to me, though I still cant decipher most of that even with that hint. And I always saw the last word as something to end with a u or a w, but that would be strange too.

Comment: Sure it is 1813 and not 1819?

Comment: I think you've nailed it spot on. And the last word does end with an "n". You can see the two bumps for the "n" with a fancy swirl as a tail, similar to the "von" at the beginning of the second line or the swirl on "im" before "Jahr" on the first line.

Comment: Here's a translation to clarify doubts: *"From the auction held by the dispatch of the "Lit. Zeitung" in the year 1813"*